# mod_wsgi on Apache: Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to use Django with Apache, but when I try to launch a WSGI application, I have the following error:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
```

I have this in the include in my httpd.conf file:

```
WSGIPythonHome /home/ec2-user/anaconda
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ec2-user/test/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/ec2-user/test
<Directory /home/ec2-user/test>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

And this is the content of my wsgi.py file:

```
import sys

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    print >> sys.stderr, 'sys.prefix = %s' % repr(sys.prefix)
    print >> sys.stderr, 'sys.path = %s' % repr(sys.path)

    return [output]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had precisely this problem. The issue is that I was using a non-standard Python and the PYTHONPATH was not being properly set.

My solution was to change this statement in my file `10-wsgi.conf`:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

To this:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIPythonHome /apps/intelpython3_2019.2/
```

Then, when wsgi starts up, it starts using my version of Intel Anaconda python, and not the default python.

In my case, I also needed to recompile `mod_wsgi` to use Python3:

```
./configure --with-python=/apps/intelpython3_2019.2/bin/python3
```

I also needed to add the Python lib to the system library:

```
$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/python3.conf 
/apps/intelpython3_2019.2/lib
```

And of course:

```
# ldconfig
```